# How to include "Page Updated" in the footer of my drupal 7 site?

Tags: 7, updating

I would like to display a "Page Updated" snippet in the footer of my site. Is there a module which I can use, and then include as a block?

Answer (score 0):

There is no module specifically to do that. Its very easy todo as you just put the message variable in the bottom of your footer. Just find the message variable in your page.tpl.php file. search for message and copy that $variable to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you. By message, you mean the text "Page last updated" or something else?
Re: message variable
Is this something I need to create, or is it already located somewhere I just need to find it?
Sorry, I am fairly new to all this